# Inefficient binary search? Hackerrank - Climbing the Leaderboard

Tags: time-limit-exceeded, go, binary-search

I'm learning Golang and have been trying to get 100% on the following Hackerrank practice challenge: [Climbing the Leaderboard](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem)

The code passes ~8 of 11 tests. The Hackerrank tests are time-bound and my code is not efficient enough to past the most intensive tests.

I'm removing duplicates from the scores using a map. Then work through each of Alice's scores to find the index of each one by doing a binary search. Given that Alice's scored are sorted, I re-use the index for the next search.

Any ideas?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    // example 1
    scores := []int32{100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10}
    alice := []int32{5, 25, 50, 120}
    r := climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)
    for a, v := range r {
        fmt.Printf("Position: %d alice[a]: %d\n", v, alice[a])
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
}

func removeDuplicates(a []int32) []int32 {
    r := []int32{}
    seen := map[int32]int32{}
    for _, val := range a {
        if _, ok := seen[val]; !ok {
            r = append(r, val)
            seen[val] = val
        }
    }
    return r
}

func getMidPoint(start, end int) int {
    i := end - start
    if i%2 == 0 {
        return i/2 + start
    }
    return (i+1)/2 + start
}

// 100 100 50 40 40 20 10
// 100 50 40 20 10
// 0   1  2  3  4
func binarySearch(scores []int32, v int32, i int) int {
    var mid int
    start := 0
    end := i

    for true {
        if end-start == 1 {
            //fmt.Printf("1 - v: %d start: %d end %d\n", v, start, end)
            if v < scores[end] {
                return end + 2
            } else if v < scores[start] {
                return start + 2
            }
            return 1
        }
        if end == 0 {
            return 1
        }

        mid = getMidPoint(start, end)

        if v > scores[mid] {
            end = mid
        } else if v < scores[mid] {
            start = mid
        } else {
            // v == scores[mid]
            //fmt.Printf("2 - v: %d start: %d end %d\n", v, start, end)
            return mid + 1
        }
    }
    return end
}

// attempt 3 - binary search
func climbingLeaderboard(originalScores []int32, alice []int32) []int32 {

    r := make([]int32, len(alice))

    //create scores and remove dups
    scores := removeDuplicates(originalScores)
    i := len(scores)

    for a, v := range alice {
        // fmt.Printf("1 - i: %d a: %d alice[a]: %d\n", i, a, alice[a])
        i = binarySearch(scores, v, i-1)
        r[a] = int32(i)
    }

    return r
}
```

Comment: Do you get "Runtime Error :(" or "Time limit exceeded" as feedback on hackerrank? It seems like the provided parsing code is broken, which fires a `panic` on test cases 6, 8 and/or 9.

Comment: @hoffmale good point. I got a "Runtime Error :(" response (I had initially assumed it was due to a timeout). How come the parsing code breaks for tests 6,8 and 9 but works for the other tests?

Comment: I tracked it down to the first loop (where it reads the original scores). My best guess would be that there's an unexpected whitespace somewhere in the input file, so `strconv.ParseInt` fails on an empty string. Most other languages (that I looked at) were far more tolerant for this case. The parsing code can be adapted to use `fmt.Fscan` to get the same behavior.as the other languages (it even simplyfies the parsing code a bit).

Comment: @hoffmale you're right. I downloaded the input data and ran it locally with some debugging comments. I'm getting an "panic: runtime error: index out of range" on the following code  `scoresItemTemp, err := strconv.ParseInt(scoresTemp[i], 10, 64)`

Comment: @hoffmale making progress... I increased the size of the Reader's memory and tests 6 and 9 now work. `reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1024*1024*3)`. Previously it couldn't read in all of the input so I was seeing this: `int(scoresCount): 200000 len(scoresTemp): 104858`. It's still failing test 8 with an ` index out of range` error when `int(scoresCount): 200000 len(scoresTemp): 200000`

Comment: Using `fmt.Fscan` did the trick for me: [Fixed `main`](https://pastebin.com/nzwpLMbJ)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79869/discussion-between-hoffmale-and-blackstone4).

Comment: Solved it. I had an error in my code... I just made a hacky change and it all works. So it was the size of the reader after all.

Answer (score 1):

As @hoffmale correctly pointed out, the Hackerrank code to read in the input files on the larger tests was causing a problem. More specifically it didn't have enough memory to read in the array. So I increased the size of the reader  and the writer (just in case). I also made a change to my binary search to ensure `end` would not be out of bounds on scores.

`reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1024*1024*3)`

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func removeDuplicates(a []int) []int {
    r := []int{}
    seen := map[int]int{}
    for _, val := range a {
        if _, ok := seen[val]; !ok {
            r = append(r, val)
            seen[val] = val
        }
    }
    return r
}

func getMidPoint(start, end int) int {
    i := end - start
    if i%2 == 0 {
        return i/2 + start
    }
    return (i+1)/2 + start
}

func binarySearch(scores []int, v int, i int) int {
    var mid int
    var end int

    start := 0
    if i >= len(scores) {
        end = len(scores) - 1
    } else {
        end = i
    }

    for true {
        if end-start == 1 {
            // fmt.Printf("1 - v: %d start: %d end %d\n", v, start, end)
            if v < scores[end] {
                return end + 2
            } else if v < scores[start] {
                return start + 2
            }
            return 1
        }
        if end == 0 {
            return 1
        }

        mid = getMidPoint(start, end)

        if v > scores[mid] {
            end = mid
        } else if v < scores[mid] {
            start = mid
        } else {
            // v == scores[mid]
            // fmt.Printf("2 - v: %d start: %d end %d\n", v, start, end)
            return mid + 1
        }
    }
    return end
}

// attempt 3 - binary search
func climbingLeaderboard(originalScores []int, alice []int) []int {

    r := make([]int, len(alice))

    //create scores and remove dups
    scores := removeDuplicates(originalScores)
    i := len(scores)

    for a, v := range alice {
        // fmt.Printf("1 - i: %d a: %d alice[a]: %d\n", i, a, alice[a])
        i = binarySearch(scores, v, i-1)
        r[a] = i
    }

    return r
}

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1024 * 1024*3)

    stdout, err := os.Create(os.Getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"))
    checkError(err)

    defer stdout.Close()

    writer := bufio.NewWriterSize(stdout, 1024 * 1024*3)

    scoresCount, err := strconv.ParseInt(readLine(reader), 10, 64)
    checkError(err)

    scoresTemp := strings.Split(readLine(reader), " ")

    var scores []int

    for i := 0; i < int(scoresCount); i++ {
        scoresItemTemp, err := strconv.ParseInt(scoresTemp[i], 10, 64)
        checkError(err)
        scoresItem := int(scoresItemTemp)
        scores = append(scores, scoresItem)
    }

    aliceCount, err := strconv.ParseInt(readLine(reader), 10, 64)
    checkError(err)

    aliceTemp := strings.Split(readLine(reader), " ")

    var alice []int

    for i := 0; i < int(aliceCount); i++ {
        aliceItemTemp, err := strconv.ParseInt(aliceTemp[i], 10, 64)
        checkError(err)
        aliceItem := int(aliceItemTemp)
        alice = append(alice, aliceItem)
    }

    result := climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)

    for i, resultItem := range result {
        fmt.Fprintf(writer, "%d", resultItem)

        if i != len(result) - 1 {
            fmt.Fprintf(writer, "\n")
        }
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(writer, "\n")

    writer.Flush()
}

func readLine(reader *bufio.Reader) string {
    str, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
    if err == io.EOF {
        return ""
    }

    return strings.TrimRight(string(str), "\r\n")
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        // fmt.Println("Error: " + err.Error())
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, no need to rewrite binary search when [sort.Search](https://golang.org/pkg/sort#Search) is available.

Comment: True - I was doing it as a learning exercise.